# convertView is being passed as null even if the view exists

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, convertview

I have developed an android application where image and text are displayed in a grid view and when the user scrolls down next ten items(image and text) are displayed. The problem arises when the getView method of adapter is called after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() call. The adapter recycles the data but positions are rearranged and repeated in grid view. I hadn't faced this problem till I added the condition to check if convertView is null.

Activity class :

```
public class DynamicListViewActivity extends Activity implements
    OnScrollListener {

int visibleElements;
int scrollState;
int count;
TextAdapter adapter = new TextAdapter();
int total=200;// total items limit in grid view


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.grid);
    count=10;
    GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    grid.setOnScrollListener(this);

}

public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, int visibleCount,
        int totalCount) {
    visibleElements= visibleCount;
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView v, int s) {
    Log.d("ScrollState", s+"");
    scrollState=s;
    isScrollStateComplete();
}

public void isScrollStateComplete(){
if(visibleElements>0 && scrollState==SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && total>count){
        int diff=total-count;
        count+=(diff>=10)?10:diff;//update count to next ten items
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


class TextAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup p) {

        View v = convertView;
        System.out.println("pos : "+pos+" boolean "+(v==null));// log to check position and convertView
                  if(v==null){
            v =((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.textlayout,null);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.album_thumbnail);
            iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));

            TextView tvAlbumName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.album_name);
            tvAlbumName.setText("postion "+pos);

            TextView tvAlbumDesc = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.album_description);
            tvAlbumDesc.setText("");

           }

          return v;
    }
}
}
```

Before scrolling grid view displays properly. Log :

```
08-05 14:24:34.440: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent {  act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.mis.list.demo/.DynamicListViewActivity }
08-05 14:24:34.642: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 0 boolean true
08-05 14:24:34.710: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 0 boolean false
08-05 14:24:34.710: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 1 boolean true
08-05 14:24:34.730: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 2 boolean true
08-05 14:24:34.800: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 3 boolean true
08-05 14:24:34.860: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 4 boolean true
08-05 14:24:34.880: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 5 boolean true
08-05 14:24:34.910: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 6 boolean true
08-05 14:24:34.920: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 7 boolean true
08-05 14:24:34.960: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 0 boolean true
08-05 14:24:35.030: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.mis.list.demo/.DynamicListViewActivity: 520 ms (total 520 ms)
```

After first end of scroll

```
08-05 14:26:15.740: DEBUG/ScrollState(685): 1
08-05 14:26:15.830: DEBUG/dalvikvm(685): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3624 objects / 257464 bytes in 71ms
08-05 14:26:16.210: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 8 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.210: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 9 boolean true
08-05 14:26:16.250: DEBUG/ScrollState(685): 0
08-05 14:26:16.260: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 0 boolean true
08-05 14:26:16.271: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 0 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.271: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 1 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.271: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 2 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.271: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 3 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.271: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 4 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.271: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 5 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.280: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 6 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.280: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 7 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.280: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 8 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.280: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 9 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.280: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 10 boolean false
08-05 14:26:16.280: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 11 boolean true
08-05 14:26:16.371: DEBUG/dalvikvm(685): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 644 objects / 33224 bytes in 41ms
08-05 14:26:45.270: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(685): No keyboard for id 0
08-05 14:26:45.270: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(685): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-05 14:26:45.341: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 12 boolean true
08-05 14:26:45.351: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 13 boolean true
08-05 14:26:45.371: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 14 boolean true
08-05 14:26:45.380: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 15 boolean true
08-05 14:26:45.450: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 16 boolean false
08-05 14:26:45.450: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 17 boolean false
08-05 14:26:45.460: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 18 boolean false
08-05 14:26:45.460: INFO/System.out(685): pos : 19 boolean false
```

But the grid displays with repeated values and not in the order it should.
Sorry i am not allowed to post images as i am new user.

In the log i see that for position 0 convertView==null is true.

how to set this right as i plan to download images in the place of android icon for image view currently used.

Please help.

Comment: In case no View is available for reuse, Android will pass null to the convertView parameter

Answer (score 13):

Your interpretation of convertView is incorrect.

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    //If convertView is null create a new view, else use convert view
    if (v == null)
        v = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.textlayout, null);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.album_thumbnail);
    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));

    TextView tvAlbumName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.album_name);
    tvAlbumName.setText("postion "+pos);

    TextView tvAlbumDesc = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.album_description);
    tvAlbumDesc.setText("");

    return v;
}
```

is what you should be doing.

As a result of what you were doing, in cases where `convertView` was not null, you were just returning convertView without updating your data, and hence your images were being repeated. Only in cases where `convertView` was null were you setting your data.

Contract between the adapter and the list view system: If the passed `convertView` is null, create a new one, else re-use it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply vikram. But i am doing the same as i do not want an existing view to be recreated. As you can see the code. If convertView is null then create view and finally return view. I even added an else statement to check if that would work but the result is same.

Comment: You must leave that to the system. The system optimizes this. And besides, when getView(View,Position) is called, you must update the View with the data at the Position, which you are not doing.

[Watch this](www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: Hey thanks Vikram. I ll check that and rectify. thanks a ton. Now i get it. :)

Comment: I had tried with this example: http://androidarena.co.in/custom-listview-using-baseadapter-hike-and-whatsapp-like-listview/ but facing same issue as in the question. Where is wrong in code?

Answer (score 4):

**Vikram Bodicherla** is correct (+1), your implementation is incorrect, and his code sample properly fixes your issue. However, I want to recommend the following Google I/O 2010 talk: [The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70). It is one hour long, but you will have a much deeper understanding of how the `ListView` works and how you should write your adapter to properly cooperate with it.

Answer (score 0):

If Android determines that a View which represents a row is not visible anymore it allows the getView() method to reuse it via the convertView parameter.

A performance optimized adapter assigns the new data to the convertView. This avoids inflating an XML file and creating new Java objects.

In case no View is available for reuse, Android will pass null to the convertView parameter. Therefore the adapter implementation need to check for this.